NextJS - Setup/install Capactior on existing repo or on duplicate?
I have my NextJS application completed. And it is pretty big application that uses both getServerSideProps() and getStaticProps(). And also have API routes in it.
I am trying to create a mobile app out of it. Found that Capacitor is way too easier. But my question is, can I install the Capacitor on my existing repo (for the currently running NextJS web application, hosted in Vercel) or should I make a duplicate of that repo and work on it?
Because there would be updates in the future and I just want to get an idea on how it can be continued.
